# NuGet get package version using ApiKey

Tags: .net, nuget

I'm trying to get the version(s) of a NuGet package using the API Key. There is ample documentation on the web on how to do a `push` using the API Key, but I cannot find if it's possible to do any other operations using it.

Specifically, I'm trying to do `nuget list` using the API Key so I don't have to hardcode user information in a script. (This is against a private repo and requires authentication).

This doesn't work:
`nuget list id:<MyPackage> -ApiKey <MyApiKey>`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NuGet get package version using ApiKey

As you can see from [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-list), `nuget list` command does not have an option to use **ApiKey**.

And from you description, you wrote a script and then did not want to invoke ApiKey, you can just save your Apikey in `%AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` file.

If nuget cannot find info under command line, it will under the file by default automatically.

**Solution**

**First**, run CMD as administrator and then type this:

```
nuget setapikey xxxxxx<your apikey>
```

It will store your apikey under the global `nuget.config` file. And after that, you don't have to worry about entering redundant apikey anymore, it will automatically get it from that file by default.

**Then**, you could call `nuget list xxx<package_name>` to obtain what you want.

**In addition**, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-exe-cli-reference) to get more steps about nuget.exe client tool.